# htaccess rule on a js file

Tags: linux, .htaccess

in my public folder I have a javascript file, data.js  that is being called from various parts of my app. I want to add a .htaccess rules to that directory so that whenever data.js is called, the request should be redirected to index.php
How would I go about doing so? I am not much familiar with .htaccess so any code example will be great.

so far I have this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   data.js      index.php?q=$1 [QSA]

but this does not retain my query parameters!
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? If not, why not? Mod rewrite it something which is very common and [well documented](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: I edited the question above. Any idea?